# python unittest assertIsInstance unexpected result

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have an issue with asserting an object is an instance of a class
In the below class you would see that obj is indeed an instance of TrieNode
However, it is failing the unittest complaining it is a Bool

```
from collections import defaultdict


class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.is_word = False

    def suffixes(self, suffix = ''):
        """
        Recursive function that collects the suffix for
        all complete words below this point
        """
        pass


class Trie(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def add(self, word):
        """
        Add `word` to trie
        """
        current_node = self.root

        for char in word:
            current_node = current_node.children[char]

            current_node.is_word = True

    def exists(self, word):
        """
        Check if word exists in trie
        """
        current_node = self.root

        for char in word:
            if char not in current_node.children:
                return False

            current_node = current_node.children[char]

        return current_node.is_word

    def find(self, prefix):
        """
        Find the Trie node that represents this prefix
        :param prefix: For example 'f'
        :return: TrieNode 'f':{...}
        """
        current_node = self.root

        for char in prefix:
            if char not in current_node.children:
                return False

            current_node = current_node.children[char]

        return current_node


my_trie = Trie()
wordList = [
    "ant", "anthology", "antagonist", "antonym",
    "fun", "function", "factory",
    "trie", "trigger", "trigonometry", "tripod"
]
for word in wordList:
    my_trie.add(word)


obj = my_trie.find('a')
print(type(obj))                   # <class '__main__.TrieNode'>
print(isinstance(obj, TrieNode))   # True
```

As you could see above I got

```
  print(type(node_a))                   # <class '__main__.TrieNode'>
  print(isinstance(node_a, TrieNode))   # True
```

Now I have this unittest

```
import unittest
from problem_05_trie_autocomplete import Trie, TrieNode


class TestTrieAutoComplete(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    python -m unittest
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_trie = Trie()

    def test_add_to_trie(self):
        """
        Add words to Trie and check their existence
        :return:
        """

        word_list = [
            "ant", "anthology", "antagonist", "antonym",
            "fun", "function", "factory",
            "trie", "trigger", "trigonometry", "tripod"
        ]
        for word in word_list:
            self.my_trie.add(word)
            self.assertTrue(self.my_trie.exists(word))

    def test_assert_is_trienode(self):
        obj = self.my_trie.find('a')
        self.assertIsInstance(obj, TrieNode)

    def test_assert_is_with_type_trienode(self):
        obj1 = self.my_trie.find('a')
        self.assertIs(type(obj1), TrieNode)
```

I got two errors in the last two tests

```
self.assertIsInstance(obj, TrieNode)
AssertionError: False is not an instance of <class 'problem_05_trie_autocomplete.TrieNode'>
======================
self.assertIs(type(obj1), TrieNode)
AssertionError: <class 'bool'> is not <class 'problem_05_trie_autocomplete.TrieNode'>

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Why is this that obj and obj1 are Bool in the unittest meanwhile in the class obj is an instance of TrieNode as it should be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: ``find`` returns a node *or ``False``*. Your tree generated in ``setUp`` is empty, so there is no node to find – and you get ``False``.

Comment: FWIW, this is why one should raise an exception if no item can be found, instead of return *some* value that is not sensible without checking it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @MisterMiyagi

Here is the solution for someone who faces the same issue
The point to learn is that the state of my_trie in the setup function will be the state that will be used by all other tests

```
import unittest
from problem_05_trie_autocomplete import Trie, TrieNode


class TestTrie(unittest.TestCase):
    """
    python -m unittest
    """

    def setUp(self):
        self.my_trie = Trie()
        self.word_list = [
            "ant", "anthology", "antagonist", "antonym",
            "fun", "function", "factory",
            "trie", "trigger", "trigonometry", "tripod"
        ]
        for word in self.word_list:
            self.my_trie.add(word)

    def test_add_to_trie(self):
        """
        Add words to Trie and check their existence
        :return:
        """
 
        for word in self.word_list:
            self.my_trie.add(word)
            self.assertTrue(self.my_trie.exists(word))

    def test_unexisting_word(self):
        self.assertFalse(self.my_trie.exists("unexistingWord"))
        self.assertFalse(self.my_trie.find('x'))
        self.assertFalse(self.my_trie.find('y'))

    def test_assert_is_trienode(self):
        obj = self.my_trie.find('a')
        self.assertIsInstance(obj, TrieNode)

    def test_assert_is_with_type_trienode(self):
        obj1 = self.my_trie.find('a')
        self.assertIs(type(obj1), TrieNode)
```